# GRUB menu does not appear after "Welcome to GRUB!"

Tags: linux, grub, bios

The GRUB welcome message appears, and disappears after a moment, then there is a blank screen. However, it still responds to Ctrl+Alt+Del, in the same way as [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90390/black-screen-after-grub).

My issue has all of the symptoms of when GRUB was installed for BIOS instead of UEFI, but my motherboard doesn't support UEFI. I have confirmed this using the output of `dmidecode -t 0`, which does not mention UEFI. Running the same command on a PC that does support UEFI yields `UEFI is supported` at the bottom of the `Characteristics` section.

I followed [this guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_ZFS) for using ZFS as the root file system on Arch. I don't think ZFS is the issue though, because I don't get to the GRUB menu screen, let alone mounting filesystems.

Comment: dmidecode doesn't yield UEFI identifiers if you weren't booted up with UEFI to begin with.

Comment: @Shadur I didn't know that, that's useful information for the future. I did check a different way by installing Ubuntu, which installed GRUB using BIOS, so I reinstalled Arch using that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I reinstalled, I did two things differently:

- My root partition was supposed to be specified as `Solaris Root` instead of `Linux Filesystem`
- I created a separate `/boot` directory, with `ext4` as the filesystem

One of these fixed my issue, but I'm not sure which.